# Strange app name after launching debug build type

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, build, android-build-type

I"ve added `debug` build type my app .gradle

```
buildTypes {
        getByName("debug") {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".debug"
            isDebuggable = true
            versionNameSuffix = " Debug"
            resValue("string", "app_name", "Name Debug")
        }
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            resValue("string", "app_name", "Name")
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")

        }
    }
```

I've removed app_name from my strings.xml but when I install my app on phone the name is "View Pager Dots indicator" what is really strange.

My manifest:

```
 <application
        android:name=".StartApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_app"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_app_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup, LockedOrientationActivity">
```

Comment: Probably that library has a string resource named `app_name` that you are picking up. Rather than use `resValue()`, you might try using source sets (put the real name in `main/res/values/` and put the debug name in `debug/res/values/`).

Comment: I"ve created /debug and put there strings.xml with my "Name Debug". The app name is still "Name" but package is ..myname.debug. Am I still missing something?

Comment: Hmm on one phone "Name Debug" displays correctly but on second it's still only "Name"

Comment: "but package is ..myname.debug" -- sorry, I am uncertain what you mean here. If you mean that your `debug` `applicationId` is taking effect, but your `app_name` is not... something strange is going on with resource merging. Resources in app modules should override any same-named resources coming from libraries.

Comment: I mean package name for my release and debug build are ok. (.debug for debug and without any suffix for release).  Only one thing that makes me wonder is that on one phone "Debug" is missing